# Route API with "via points"

Tags: php, jquery, routes, openstreetmap

Firstable i was looking for solution to my problem, but cannot find any answer, so i hope is there someone who has similiar issue.

I have a GPS tracker in my car. Data from gps tracker i store in mysql db.
For viewing data i use openstreetmap.

My issue is showing history of these logs.

I wanna show line to follows road.
I found this web based api [YOURS](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/YOURS#Usage) and i think it's way BUT!!
To prevent too many calls I wanna call api with viewpoints as "via" to set route option. "via points" may be 10 or 100 - I adjust to API options.

So my question is, how can i send to API gps coords of route with "via points" ?
Or is there any free api for commercial use to get points of crossroads that supports "via point"?
I'm not prefering googleAPI's because i calculate with 1 req/minute in average.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With so many requests please consider installing a local router. Choose one of the many [available routers for OSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing), for example [GraphHopper](https://graphhopper.com/) or [OSRM](http://project-osrm.org/).

Answer (score 0):

The [GraphHopper Directions API](https://graphhopper.com/api/1/docs/routing/) supports several via points depending on the [chosen package](https://graphhopper.com/#pricing).

But I think you need a solution like the [map matching](https://github.com/graphhopper/map-matching) to solve your problem in a more stable way?

Note: I'm a co-founder of GraphHopper